# How to do a Sign Up with OAuth (facebook, twitter, google)?

Tags: authentication, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0

I use Laravel (5) as my php framework, it recently added a library for social authentication (facebook, google, twitter and github).

I've been wondering how would you do a Sign Up with OAuth, a login can easily be done by getting the user's email via OAuth, checking if it exists in your DB, and if it does, then log in that user. But how would you do the Sign Up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathius - I've recently been working on a site doing something similar to what you've described and this is what has worked for me:

```
public function syncUserDetails($userData)
{
    // First I check to see if there is a user in the DB
    // with the oAuth email address
    if ( $user = $this->user->where('email', $userData->email)->first() )
    {
        // If there is a user, I simply update their local info
        // with what is on their oAuth account

        $user->token = $userData->token;
        $user->google_id = $userData->id;
        $user->name = $userData->name;
        $user->avatar = $userData->avatar;
        $user->first_name = $userData->user['given_name'];
        $user->last_name = $userData->user['family_name'];
        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }

    // Otherwise, if the user doesn't already exist,
    // I create them in my local user's DB

    return $this->user->firstOrCreate([
        'email'      => $userData->email,
        'token'      => $userData->token,
        'google_id'  => $userData->id,
        'name'       => $userData->name,
        'avatar'     => $userData->avatar,
        'first_name' => $userData->user['given_name'],
        'last_name'  => $userData->user['family_name']
    ]);
}
```

This is what I'm using to log in a user. However, you could just as easily run this alongside your regular Laravel login method.

Comment: Thanks! Excellent response. In my web app the user can sign up via social but can also do it via a form, so I guess that if they sign up via OAuth the password field would be left empty.